# Tomcat authentication configured inside the war

Tags: security, authentication, tomcat, war

I have to deploy a war to a tomcat but I cannot modify anything outside the war itself.
Now I need to add authentication and authorization to the application.

The basic authentication would be enough but I cannot edit the tomcat-user.xml file, nor I can depend on absoulute paths as suggestend here: [How do I provide basic http authentication for static tomcat webapps without changing tomcat-users.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726014/how-do-i-provide-basic-http-authentication-for-static-tomcat-webapps-without-cha)

I just need to use a single user/password that can be configured in a file inside the war (it's a simple application with short lifetime and really low security requirements).
What is the simplest way to do this?

Thanks
Andrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems that a solution is to use spring security with basic authentication.

See: [Spring Security HTTP Basic Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691160/spring-security-http-basic-authentication)

In my original case I didn't want to include spring security but I still don't know any other way to obtain this result.